# Pandas Mask Performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I was having trouble with pandas with a heavy file that I would filter. I tested this two forms to make the filtering, and one make in about 30% the time. My question is why the mask generated perform better than passing the filter in the dataframe?

My codes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.randint(low=1,high=100,size=10*8), 'data':np.random.randint(low=1,high=100,size=10*8)})
```

first approach

```
init = datetime.datetime.now()
partial = df[df['data']==5]
final = datetime.datetime.now()
print(len(partial))
print(final-init)
```

1011055
time: 0:00:00.611047

second approach:

```
init = datetime.datetime.now()
mask == df['data']==5
partial = df[mask]
final = datetime.datetime.now()
print(len(partial))
print(final-init)
```

1011055
0:00:00.377024

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now()` is not intended to measure execution time correctly. Use module `timeit`. You may get very different results.

Comment: did you mean to have `mask ==`? instead of `mask =`? assuming that - i don't see any noticeable difference either way

Comment: I made two misstypos whe I was writeing my code one is the `mask =` sign and the other is the key data df = pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.randint(low=1,high=100,size=10*8), 'data_b':np.random.randint(low=1,high=100,size=10*8)}), I guess this would influence the time of the execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see much of a difference:

```
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=10*8)})

t1 = timeit("partial = df[df['data'] == 5]", number=10000, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("mask = (df['data'] == 5); partial = df[mask]", number=10000,
            globals=globals())
print(t1, t2)
```

Result:

```
2.363040907 2.3674299340000005
```